# Largest permutation of subset of $[n]$ with the property that every element in the right half is near to ($<n/2$ from) every element in the left half

Tags: induction, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, integers, pigeonhole-principle

Let $\ n\in\mathbb{N}\ $ and consider rearrangements/permutations, $\ \sigma_k\ (k\leq n)$ of subsets of $\ [n]:= \{ 1,2,\ldots, n\}\ $ with the property that no member of the right half of $\ \sigma_k\ $ is greater than $\ \frac{n}{2}\ $ distance away from a member of the left half of $\ \sigma_k.\ $

So, for example, for $\ n=80,\ $ the arrangement $\ 4, 61 \vert 23, 5\ $ has left half $\ 4, 61,\ $ and right half $\ 23, 5.\ $ This arrangement fails to satisfy the desired property because $\ 61 - 5 > 40.$

An example in $n=80$ that does satisfy the property is $\ 35, 28, 53\vert 19, 37, 63,\ $ because everything in the left half is not further than $40$ away from anything in the right half.

My question is: what the maximum value of is $k$ , i.e., the cardinality of a rearranged subset of $[n]$ with the desired property?

I have been able to figure out is that $k$ cannot equal $n$ because in the $n=80$ example, whatever half contains $\ 1\ $ would need to contain $\ 42\to 80,\ $ but then (due to pigeonhole principle) $\ 2\ $ would have to be in the other half, but $\ 80-2>40.$

Also, $\ k\geq n/2$ because of $\ 1\to \frac{n}{4}\ \Big\vert\ (\frac{n}{4}+1)\to n/2.$

But with the $n=80$ example, we can add larger numbers onto the left-hand side to get, for example: $\ 44\to 41, 1\to 18\ \Big\vert\ 19\to 40,\ $ and so $\ k\geq 44,\ $ and you can do this up to $\ 54\ $ instead of $\ 44,\ $ but I'm not sure how to improve on that.

The following table might have mistakes, but it is my attempt to find the best sequences for some small values of $n$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
  \text{n} & \text{Example maximal permutation subset} & \text{k} \\ 
\hline
   \mathbb{4} & 1,4 \vert 2,3 & 4 \\
\hline
   \mathbb{6} & 1,4 \vert 2,3 & 4 \\
\hline
   \mathbb{8} & 1,6,2 \vert 5,3,4 & 6 \\ 
\hline
   \mathbb{10} & 1,8,2,7 \vert 3,6,4,5 & 8 \\ 
\hline
   \mathbb{12} & 1,8,2,7 \vert 3,6,4,5 & 8 \\ 
\hline
   \mathbb{14} & 1,10,2,9,3 \vert 8,4,7,5,6 & 10 \\ 
\hline
   \mathbb{16} & 1,12,2,11,3,10 \vert 4,9,5,8,7,6 & 12 \\ 
\hline
   \mathbb{18} & 1,12,2,11,3,10 \vert 4,9,5,8,7,6 & 12 \\ 
\hline
   \mathbb{20} & 1,14,2,13,3,12,4 \vert 11,5,10,6,9,7,8 & 14 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}

I imagine the details, like

- odds and even $n$
- whether it's $>40$ or $\geq 40$

don't matter, because I imagine the behaviour is similar in terms of the asymptotic value of $\ k(n)\ $ which is what I'm interested in. It feels like it should have to do with some logarithmic function.

Comment: Not sure I understand the rules.  Do you need every element on one side to be near every element on the other side?  Or just near *some* element on the other side?  For $n=8$, say, can you do better than $3,4\,|\,5,6$?

Comment: Well, for $8$, I guess you can do $2,6,7\,|\,3,4,5$, yeah?  What is the sequence of maximal sizes?

Comment: I think you can get $2/3$ of the numbers in.  The left includes $1$ to $n/6$ and $n/2+1$ to $2n/3$, while the right has $n/6+1$ to $n/2$

Comment: @lulu yes, every element on the left-hand side must be close to every element on the right-hand side. No two elements in opposite halves can be more than $n/2$ apart. And yes, I want the sequence(s) with greatest number of elements in them, for a given $n$. Or more importantly, I want the cardinality of that sequence in terms of some function of $n$.

Comment: The way you phrased the header question is ambiguous (at best).  You said "no element in the right half is further than n/2 from an element in the left half."  And, what is the sequence of maximal sizes?  It can't be hard to sort this out for small $n$, no?

Comment: Please clarify what is ambiguous about the header. I'm not seeing it. And I'm not sure, I didn't find a straightforward pattern for small $n,$ but I'll have another look.

Comment: Just list the values for small $n$.  I read the header as saying "for each element $R$ on the right side there exists an element $L$ on the left side such that $|R-L|≤\frac n2$"

Comment: Oh yeah, I see the pattern now. It's simpler than I thought...

Comment: So now I understand Empy2's comment, and I think he is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler than I first thought. In order to minimise the (maximum) distance between the left and right half, I think we carry on the pattern in the table in the question, and so our largest permutation should be of the form:

$$ \left[\ \text{lower quarter of } [k]\ \right] , [\ \text{ upper quarter of } [k]\ ] \Bigg\vert\ [\  \text{middle half of } [k]\ ]\ , $$

in which case the maximum distance between members of the left half and members of the right half is $\ \approx \frac{3}{4} k,\ $ which should be equal to $\frac{n}{2}$ if we are maximising. So we get: $\ \approx \frac{3}{4} k = \frac{n}{2},\ \implies k \approx \frac{2}{3} n,\ $ or to be more precise, it would be something like, $\ k = \frac{2}{3}n \pm 4,$ or maybe $\pm 2,$ but as I'm not interested in this detail, it doesn't really matter.